# What is a word or phrase that indicates asking all participants in a meeting to speak in turn?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a concise and unambiguous phrase (or word) that indicates a structure where everyone will be given a turn to talk (ideally without interruption for debate).

Example:

"After **a period where everyone will be given, in turn, an opportunity to share their point of view**, we will have an open discussion of the points raised".  The phrase in bold is what I would like a concise alternative for.

Example 2:
"Please save the debate until after the XXX" (instead of "please save the debate until after everyone has had their turn to talk")

**Rejects:**
I've been using "round-robin", and "round-table", but I suspect both of those are wrong, as round robin in sports generally indicates all permutations of pairs, and round-table is open to a more free-style discussion format where louder and more outspoken participants might dominate.

Comment: They will opine one by one.

Comment: Age 7 and under: *After we take turns sharing, we will have...* Everyone else: *After an opinion-sharing session, will have...*

Comment: It's funny that English doesn't have many terms for democratic ways of doing things. "round robin" and "round table" typically have more specific, different meanings. You just have to use a more descriptive phrase like "everybody has their chance to speak".

Comment: I am hoping there's an academic branch that tackles and names these structures...

Comment: "After we share our views in turn, we will have..." Note how basic this phrase is. That evokes the longstanding nature of ordered assemblies where everyone can speak their minds (the origin I'm not sure, but probably 1500s if not earlier). It's only the translation from corporate language to ordinary language that is proving difficult. One of these is obviously more modern and artificial than the other!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**go around the room**

I've heard this idiom often used for the situation; e.g.:

> Let's go 'round the room and give everyone a chance to voice their opinion. 
> Jim...
> Angie...
> Sandeep...
> Jimmy...
> etc..